# Change location of popup box in style sheet?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I am using the following code to generate a popup box

```
        <cc1:modalpopupextender ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" TargetControlID="cmdHospitalNew"
    PopupControlID="popupError" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true"
    OkControlID="SubmitOk" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
</cc1:modalpopupextender>
<div class="popupConfirmation" id="popupError" style="display: none; background-color: White;
    width: 200px; height: auto;">
    <div id="popupErrorMessage" style="width: 190px">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_DB_popupError" runat="server" Text="Please fill all required fields!"></asp:Label></div>
    <div id="popupErrorSubmitOk">
        <input type="submit" id="SubmitOk" value="OK" style="visibility: visible;" /></div>
```

Is there a way to move this to the middle-Top-Left? Right now the popup is in the center of the screen. Here is the stylesheet I am using:

```
body {
}

.ModalPopupBG
{
background-color: #666699;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.7;

}
```

Comment: Can you do `float: left;` and then vertical align it to the top?

Comment: Wierd I added the float: left; and it is still in the same location

Comment: Have you inspected the page to see what styles are actually applied to the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modifiy the `CSS` to include `top` & `left` positions based on where you want it to appear:

```
.ModalPopupBG
{
    background-color: #666699;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Also, your code shows:

`BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"`

This should be:

`CssClass="ModalPopupBG"`.

Comment: I added that but it is still in the same location am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are in `position: fixed;` when you want to be `position: absolute;`, try that instead.

If that does not work, then try `position: absolute!important;` and see if that forces it to absolute position.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these 3 lines to your .ModalPopupBG class

```
position:absolute;
top:300px;
left:300px;
```

and tweak the pixels until it lines up to where you want it.